# Send Conversation History API returning HTTP 400 BotFramework

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I'm trying to sendConversation History API provided by Microsoft in [BotFramework Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-conversation-history). It takes Transcript object (array of activities) as the input. But I've getting HTTP 400 Bad Request when using trying that.

I'm making a POST request on this and authenticating it using JWT Token generated by client credentials for the bot.

```
https://directline.botframework.com/v3/conversations/HBoZPkTiBYOAadigqEqFaJ-us/activities/history
```

This is the error I get.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Invalid or missing activities"
    }
}
```

This is the activity array payload that I'm using

```
[    
    {
        "type": "message",
        "id": "HBoZPkTiBYOAadigqEqFaJ-us|0000003",
        "timestamp": "2022-09-05T08:10:00.3574378Z",
        "localTimestamp": "2022-09-05T13:39:57.633+05:30",
        "localTimezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
        "channelId": "directline",
        "from": {
            "id": "dl_uID1",
            "name": "userName"
        },
        "conversation": {
            "id": "HBoZPkTiBYOAadigqEqFaJ-us"
        },
        "recipient": {
            "id": "bot-name-dev@abcd",
            "name": "bot-name-dev"
        },
        "textFormat": "plain",
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "text": "hi",
        "channelData": {
            "clientActivityID": "1662365337633rmq6e8mbm09",
            "clientTimestamp": "2022-09-05T08:09:57.633Z"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm not able to figure out what's the correct format of activity object that it is expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting with Microsoft, I found this is the correct payload for this API.

```
{
  "activities": [
   
       {
    "type": "message",
    "id": "whatever-conversation-id-in|0000000",
    "timestamp": "2022-11-20T20:14:26.242902Z",
    "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
    "channelId": "directline",
    "from": {
        "id": "dl_test_id",
        "name": ""
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "whatever-conversation-id-in"
       
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "ABC_bot",
        "name": "ABC_bot"
    },
    "text": "Hello Bot"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the bot and get it connected to the Direct Line. Get the secret keys of the site that need to connect.
Before calling **SendConversationHistory** if the message is delivered to the recipient, it will create the bad request error message as it is unable to get the conversation history as the message was already received. **SendConversationHistory** must be called before sending the message then the Conversation History will be tracked. The below screens will be helpful to create the **DirectLine** connection to the bot created. Then needed to add the trusted sites to **DirectLine**. Then proceed with the code sample mentioned below which takes the conversation history.

[image]

Click on **Create a resource**

[image]

Search for **bot** and click on **create**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Select **Channels**

[image]

[image]

Get the **App Service Extension Keys** and click on **Default_site**

[image]

Click on the toggle and **enable the enhanced authentication** options and add the website which we need to communicate.
In the code block of the current working application, to get the conversation history, use the following code block.

```
foreach (var a in activities)
{
    incrementId++;
    // Use your own ID format
    a.Id = string.Concat("history|", incrementId.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0'));
    a.ChannelData = null;
    a.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: convId);

    if (a.From.Name == message.Recipient.Name)
    {
        // Bot to recipient connection 
        a.Recipient = message.From;
        a.From = message.Recipient;
    }
    else
    {
        // User to bot connection (here bot will be the recipient)
        a.Recipient = message.Recipient;
        a.From = message.From;
    }
}
```